# How can I run a "hello, world!" programme?

Tags: c

I have this basic program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf("Hello, world!");
    
    return 0;
}
```

but how can I saw the compiler said: Hello, world!
and how can I start it?
sorry if it's simple but I'm new.

Comment: This depends on your environment; if you [edit] your question to tell us about it, we might be able to give more info. The compiler will convert the `.c` file to a `.exe` or ELF (Linux executable) which you can run to see the output. If you are using an IDE like VSCode/Codeblocks/Visual Studio/etc, it may automatically combine these steps into an automated build process.

Comment: It's just i'm on VS code and i want to now how to run a programme

Comment: The necessary steps depend on your operating system (Windows/Mac/Linux)

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed?

Comment: I'm on microsoft

Comment: VS code don't have a compilateur preinstalled ?

Comment: VS Code is a modular IDE (initially developed for TypeScript development), it does not come with a C compiler. You have to install the compiler separately

Comment: @cocoFox It does not. One option is https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp for language support plus http://www.mingw-w64.org/doku.php as one possible compiler you may use.

Comment: When i'm on microsoft and i download minGW i do what else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using any UNIX (Linux/Mac) machine it's pretty simple:

1. You open up the terminal in the folder your program is located.
2. For example you type in `gcc "program_name.c" -o "program_name"` to compile the program
3. And now you have to execute the program in the terminal typing this `./"program_name"`

you can put whatever you like in the "program_name" :)

Comment: I'm on microsoft

Comment: Also not every Linux distribution (or macOS) ships with a compiler pre-installed, you often have to install that via the package manager

Comment: @KiwiBoaye You don't need to put the quotes (`"`).

Comment: Yea, sorry I thought it would be more explanatory if I put quotes for the example's purpose :)

Comment: When i'm on microsoft and i download  minGW i do what else ?

Comment: I think that you should first configure your PATH environment variables in order to compile the program as I showed in the example :)

Comment: did you now a video how show how to do this in a very new beginner

Comment: I installed minGW configure all that had to be done and when I have to run hello.exe it says: 'hello' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an executable program or a batch file.

Comment: It might be because of the architecture your machine is running on, so be sure that you are compiling the code in the correct system .